# Is there any way to provide share option after download file using file transfer plugin

Tags: ionic3, file-transfer, socialshare

I have a file on server and i download it from server using file transfer plugin and open it using fileopen plugin but it having issue on some devices that downloaded file not open. and how to provide social sharing option after download the file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any idea about sharing a downloaded file using **Ionic3**.
But you can try following steps:

1. Download a file at a specific path like WhatsApp data. (for your project lets say com.project.com and then in **Download** folder).
2. Open a downloaded file using phone's default application. Most of the reader application comes with **share** and **edit** option. They will share your file wherever you want.

Comment: I did that but in some device that downloaded file not showing.

Comment: I also faced the same issue, later found that it does not get downloaded on the same path for iOS and Android, so I was unable to open that. Is that same case with you?

Comment: You can refer this two links: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/ and https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files

Comment: Yes. Same issue

Comment: @rawathemant, You may need to work differently for different platform. For iOS and Android need handle from where the file will open.

Comment: thanks @Pradnya Sinalkar, now i'm using this script http://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-3-share-and-save-images-from-applications-assets-folder-to-device/